# Tag Search System SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to make a system where you can search posts based on tags (using a SQL db).

Example schema:

Post: id, name

Tag: id, name, post_id (foreign_key)

Example Object:

```
Posts:

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Post1"
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Post2"
}

Tags:

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tag1",
    "post_id": 1
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tag2",
    "post_id": 1
}

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Tag1",
    "post_id": 2
}
```

Example, I search with Tag1 and Tag2

I want to get back a list with relevance (how many tags matched).

Example:

```
{
    "post_id": 1,
    "tag_count": 2
}

{
    "post_id": 2,
    "tag_count": 1
}
```

Id started with:

```
select * from recipes_tag where name in ("tag1", "tag2")
```

But I can't find a way to count by the post_id to see how many tags each post has in the search.

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses `'` to quote strings.

Then you can just use aggregation to count the tags...

```
SELECT
  post_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT name)  AS count_of_tags
FROM
  recipes_tag
WHERE
 name IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
GROUP BY
  post_id
```

If you want to ensure there are at least a certain number of matches, add this to the end...

```
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT name) = 2
```